# jQuery значение переменной как имя ключа в многомерном массиве

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть некий набор чекбоксов

```
<input type=checkbox name="def" id="def" value="value1:case1">
<input type=checkbox name="def" id="def" value="value2:case2">
<input type=checkbox name="def" id="def" value="value3:case1">
<input type=checkbox name="def" id="def" value="value4:case2">
```

Мне надо перебрать их и получить на выходе строку вида "value1, value3 case1; value2, value4 case2;"

С javascript/jQuery не очень.. Что-то я запутался, никак не могу понять как правильно затолкать все в многомерный массив и потом правильно его перебрать.. В PHP все как-то проще.. Попытки:

```
$("input:checkbox[name=def]").click(function() {
    var myarr = {};
    var tmparr = [];
    var k = '';
    var v = '';
    var i = 0;
    $("input:checkbox[name=def]:checked").each(function(){
        tmparr = $(this).val().split(":");
        k = tmparr[0];
        v = tmparr[1];
        //на этом месте фантазия иссякла (
        i++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // обозначим объект
  var obj = {};
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {

    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    var key = $(this).val().split(':')[0];
    var val = $(this).val().split(':')[1];   
    
    // если нет такого ключа, создаем в виде массива
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) { 
      obj[key] = [];
    } 
    
    // если выбран чекбокс добавляем к соответ-му ключу, 
    if (checked) {               
      obj[key].push(val);
    } else {
    // иначе удаляем   
      var index = obj[key].indexOf(val);
      if (index > -1) {
        obj[key].splice(index, 1);
      } 
    }
    
    console.log(obj);
    //console.log(obj['1']);
    //console.log(obj['2']);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=checkbox name="def" id="def" value="1:val1">
<input type=checkbox name="def" id="def" value="1:val2">
<input type=checkbox name="def" id="def" value="2:val3">
<input type=checkbox name="def" id="def" value="2:val4">
```

Comment: Во! Спасибище! Ночером думал про то что к обьекту нельзя применить push, знач надо дополнительно обьявить свойство обьекта как массив, а утром увидел Ваш ответ где собсно показано как сделать!

Comment: Незачто, успехов!

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вам подойдет такой пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    let arr = [];
    // перебор чекбоксов и добавление в массив значений выбранных
    $.each($('input[type=checkbox]'), function() {
       if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        arr.push($(this).val());
       }
    });
    console.log(arr);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=checkbox name="def" id="def" value="value1:case1">
<input type=checkbox name="def" id="def" value="value2:case2">
<input type=checkbox name="def" id="def" value="value3:case1">
<input type=checkbox name="def" id="def" value="value4:case2">
```

Comment: эмм.. собсно в обыный массив мне труда не составляло значения запихать, мне нужно на лету создать ассоциативный многомерный массив типа 
arr[case1][0] = val1
arr[case1][1] = val3
arr[case2][0] = va2
arr[case2][1] = va4

Comment: @ded-mazay, если вам нужен ассоциативный массив я думаю подойдет обычный объект объект, типичное сочетание связки ключ -> значение. https://learn.javascript.ru/object

Answer (score 0):

Пока не разобрался в тонкостях работы с массивами в Javascript/jQuery ( Пока сделал так:

```
<input type=checkbox name="def" id="def" value="кнопок:деформация">деформация<br />
<input type=checkbox name="def" id="def" value="на кнопках:загрязнения">загрязнения<br />
<input type=checkbox name="def" id="def" value="кнопок:оплавление">оплавление<br />
<input type=checkbox name="def" id="def" value="на кнопоках:отслоение/повреждения ЛКП">отслоение/повреждения ЛКП<br />
<input type=checkbox name="def" id="def" value="на кнопках:потертости">потертости<br />
<input type=checkbox name="def" id="def" value="на кнопках:царапины">царапины<br />

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
        var arr = [];
        var words = [];
        var i = 0;
        $.each($('input[type=checkbox]'), function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                var tmparr = [];
                var word = '';
                var val = '';
                tmparr = $(this).val().split(':');
                word = tmparr[0];
                val = tmparr[1];
                words[i] = word;
                arr[i] = val;
                i++;
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"http://host/script.php", //формирую нужную строку в понятном мне языке..
            data:{words:words,values:arr},
            success:function(response){
                $("textarea[name=my_info]").text(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

На выходе получаю сформированную строку, что-то на подобие "вздутие, деформация аккумулятора; загрязнения экрана; мусор/пыль между стеклом и экраном; сколы, царапины на экране;"

Но такой ход конем мне естественно совсем не интересен.., ну не понял я как работать с массивами в js... (
Вопрос актуален, хотелось бы как-то изящно одной ф-цией собрать элементы, сформировать строку, передать в другое поле инпута (тут textarea)..

Comment: Я вам ниже написал, посмотрите в сторону js объектов. Объявили объект: var obj = {}, занесли значение по ключу obj[key]=val

Comment: Мне нужен массив глубиной в 3 на сколько я понимаю: obj[key][i] = val, а так уже не получается или я не могу понять как сделать.. Если сделать obj[key] = {i:{a:val}}, то obj[key] при каждом проходе перезаписывается (присвается новое значение {i:{a:val}})..